# Create a list with items on separate lines

Tags: python, list

I have a notepad text file with a list of names

eg.

```
raymond james  
warren buffett  
ernest giles  
william blair
```

How would I turn this into a list where each list item is the WHOLE name on each line.
So my list would be:

```
['raymond james', 'warren buffet', 'ernest giles', 'william blair']
```

Comment: Use `readlines` Ex: `with open(filename) as infile:
    result = infile.readlines()`

Comment: If it is a single string, just use `those_lines.splitlines()` If it is in a file, use `.readlines()`

Comment: @dawg, `.readlines()` leaves trailing newlines, so `.read().splitlines()` should rather be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/in-python-how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `strip()` to avoid newline characters and trailing whitespaces. There is no need of `readlines()` in this case:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]

print(lines)  # ['raymond james', 'warren buffet', 'ernest giles', 'william blair']
```

Or if you don't like list comprehension, you can also use `map()` as follows:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = list(map(str.strip,f))

print(lines)
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree. I can't understand why rahlf23 got 5 upvotes.

Comment: @LaurentH. I can't understand why no one dupe voted this thing. >_>

Answer (score 5):

Simply open the file in read mode, and use the `readlines()` method:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as myfile:

    lines = myfile.readlines()
```

And you can use a simple list comprehension to remove the newline characters (`\n`):

```
lines = [i.strip() for i in lines]
```

Comment: You'll want to remove the newlines from that, according to OP's post

Comment: Updated to remove newline characters.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, files opened as text are iterable over their lines. The simplest solution is therefore

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
     my_list = list(f)
```

This is better than using `readlines` because the iterator strips newlines while `readlines` does not.

If you want to strip additional spaces from each line, as other answers suggest, you can use a comprehension:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
     my_list = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

or `map`:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
     my_list = list(map(str.strip, f))
```